# A word for: someone who is easy to talk to

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, epithet-requests

I want to convey the idea that such and such person is very easy to talk to.

I know that:

1. 'talk to-able' is not a word, obviously.
2. I can always say, "He is very easy to talk to." But I am looking for a single word, not a phrase.
3. The word 'talkable' changes the meaning. Eg, if I say, "He is very talkable," the meaning tends to become (a) either, he is a topic/subject worthy of talking, (b) or, he can be talked over or shut up easily!
4. I can get away with words like approachable, accessible, reachable etc but I feel there has got to be a better word.

Is there any?

Thanks much.

**EDIT**

Sometimes, there are people at work who, *officially*, can be 'approached' for questions. But their tone and body language, consciously or unconsciously, is such that they make you feel very uncomfortable approaching them next time around especially if there are choices available. So while they are there, 'accessible' etc for you *officially*, yet they are not all that 'easy to talk to'! Note that, I'm not necessarily looking for 'chatty' people either, but rather those who I can ask even stupid questions fearlessly because... again, they are 'very easy to talk to', with minimal ego, arrogance, and air about them.

**EDIT 2**

I am also happy with Dave Mulligan's "approachable" and ermanen's very clever "easy-to-talk-to".

Comment: We're going to need more explanation about why "approachable" etc won't work. What doesn't work about them? Why not exactly?

Comment: @thomas please see the EDIT.

Comment: What you describe in your edit @Harry is exactly what I have in my mind when I use the word winsome. Being accessible is not enough. Being approachable is better. Being comfortable is the goal. Winsome people, like Ronald Reagan or Bill Clinton (depending on your party comfort) made everyone feel more comfortable around them.

Comment: @ScotM winsome doesn't feel right to me somehow. I have upvoted your answer, though. Thanks!

Comment: @Harry With respect to your edit: _Approachable_ is still the right word, and I don't think it means what you think it means. _Approachable_, in English, does not communicate a Boolean value of yes-may-officially-be-approached or no-may-not-be, and is not tied to rank. It conveys precisely the feelings of ease, accessibility and comfort you seek. At a small company I worked at, the CEO was very _approachable_, despite myself just being a co-op there. At a company I worked in earlier, I felt some co-workers were quite _unapproachable_, even though the disparity in rank was much lesser.

Comment: Who says _talk-to-able_ is not a word? It’s precise, easily understood, and does not have any undesired meanings or nuances—it fits the bill exactly. The only problem with it is that it is perhaps a bit clumsy.

Comment: _easy-to-talk-to_

Comment: @ermanen that was ingenius! +1

Comment: perhaps friendly works as well?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[Affable:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Affable)  (from TFD)

> - Easy and pleasant to speak to; approachable.

From Etymonline we gain insight into the reason "*[Affable](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=affable&searchmode=none)*" might work to describe "people who are easy to talk to":

> - late 15c.,
> - from Old French *afable* (14c.)
> - from Latin *affabilis* "***approachable***, courteous, kind,friendly,"
> - literally "***who can be (easily) spoken to***,"
> - from *affari* "***to speak to***,"
> - from *ad- "to"* + *fari "to speak"*

NB: Reformatted for clarity. ***Emphasis*** by ScotM.

It seems affable people have been easy to talk to for a long time.

Comment: While I would prefer to use 'approachable' in my conversational English with my non-MBA, very down-to-earth coworkers, 'affable' is probably the word I was looking for, which I should be easily able to use in formal writing. Unfortunately, I cannot mark 2 answers as final, so I am picking this one. Thanks to all who took the time to respond. TIL: affable = approachable = easy-to-talk-to .

Comment: Looks nice, @cate101! So you got approachable and talk-able through the back door, Harry ;)

Comment: While I love the word "affable," in the EDIT context — a business environment where you're probably trying to help your junior colleagues find *approachable* senior colleagues or specialists — I would choose the word "approachable" instead.  Easy to talk to isn't exactly the same thing as *easy to begin a conversation with*, and I think that's more the spirit of the question.  I think there are people who are difficult or daunting to approach, and still extremely affable once you start talking.  If that makes sense?  Just my 2¢.

Answer (score 30):

I would probably choose "approachable".  You almost used it in your "Edit" paragraph, and I think it describes exactly the concept you're describing.

Comment: Yes, this word is commonly used in this context (which I know despite not being a native speaker)

Answer (score 9):

While **Affable** is clearly the most precise match...

*Personable* is often used as a synonym and is still in general use.

```
per·son·able adjective \ˈpərs-nə-bəl, ˈpər-sə-nə-bəl\
: friendly or pleasant in manner : easy to get along with
```

[source](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/personable)

Comment: I have seen people at work who are friendly, pleasant, easy to get along with, well-mannered etc UNTIL you go and try to talk to them! Strange but true. Maybe, they feel threatened sharing helpful info in a highly competetive modern IT workplace. I could write a longer essay on this specific personality type but for now 'affable' and 'approachable' seem to be most apt words to me. +1

Answer (score 6):

The loosely related word **congenial** comes to mind;

> **adjective**
>
> (of a person) pleasing or liked on account of having
>   qualities or interests that are similar to one's own.

Congenial does of course imply a specificity to oneself rather than a more generalized 'easy-to-talk-to-ness', on account of mutual interests.

[**Source**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=congenial&rlz=1C1GGGE_en-gbGB545GB546&oq=congenial&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.973j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 5):

***[Conversational](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/conversational)*** could be a generic adjective to describe a person who is easy to talk with.

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Consisting of or relating to conversation:
>
> "Her conversational demeanor convinced the boss to promote her."
>
> [ORIGIN](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=conversational&allowed_in_frame=0)
>
> from Latin *conversationem "act of living with,"* past participle stem
>   of *conversari "to live with, keep company with,"* literally *"turn
>   about with*," + *al "of, like, related to, pertaining to,"*

***[Engaging](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/engaging)*** would describe a person who connects well during a conversation.

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Charming and attractive:
>
> "She has an *engaging* voice."
>
> [ORIGIN](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=engage&allowed_in_frame=0)
>
> from phrase *en gage "under pledge,"* from *en "in"* + *gage "pledge"*

[***Winsome***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/winsome) could describe a person whose conversation you found pleasant and endearing.

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Attractive or appealing in a fresh, innocent way:
>
> "His winsome personality helps him win friends and influence
>   people."
>
> ORIGIN
>
> from the Old English word *wynn* "*joy*", which seems to be
>   related to the Latin *venus* "*love*."
>
> The suffix -*[some](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/-some#-some)* is from the Old English *sum "producing; being"*.

Together, these two phonemes yield the connotation "producing the joy of love". *Winsome* would be my favorite, but it's your word choice.

(Source: www.oxforddictionaries.com)

Comment: I guess it can be, but "conversational" is more often used for someone who talks with people a lot. A conversational person is going to try to talk to you, while someone who is easy to talk to may require you to start the conversation. In other words, conversational is more specific. The other two you mention are similarly more specific, but you already explain why.

Answer (score 5):

Half the responses here have included "friendly" in their definitions. I'd propose it as an actual answer.

Comment: It's a good one: https://bit.ly/2meeeSE

Answer (score 4):

I suggest the word **bonhomous** which means possessing an approachable disposition; very easy to talk to.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bonhomous

http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/bonhomous

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bonhomie

Comment: I'd strongly encourage not using that word.  I've never heard of it (educated, native speaker) and it is extremely uncommon.  Per Google, it didn't exist in literature prior to the 20th century, peaked in popularity some time in the 1950s, and has been declining in use since: https://bit.ly/2lSGdXV

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an adjective, but a very common English expression would call the person in question a **good listener**.  It implies everything you're trying to describe above, about the person being very "talk to-able".  Unfortunately, it's not a single word, but it is short, and very common.

Comment: I am looking for a 2-way conversation with this person :-) A good listener may never open his mouth even once, and may just keep nodding throughout.

Comment: Oh, I see.  In that case, the only words I can come up with are vague (such as "open", as in "He's a very open person - you can talk to him about anything") or carry a bit too much connotation about their personality than I suspect you'd like (e.g. "personable" or "friendly").

Comment: @Harry, while a 'good listener' could be silent, it's more likely that they would be an [active listener](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_listening). Someone who does not keep 2-way communication open - at an absolute minimum, using non-verbal communication - would not be a 'good listener'. A 'good listener' does a lot more than just literally listen!

Answer (score 3):

[***Empathetic***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/empathetic) people connect deeply with the folks around them.

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Showing an ability to understand and share the feelings of another:
>
> ORIGIN
>
> from Greek *empatheia* from *em- 'in'* + *pathos 'feeling'*

Here is how it might apply at the office:

His *empathetic* response defused the emotional bomb ticking in the office.

***[Compassionate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/compassionate?searchDictCode=all)*** is the verbal cousin of empathetic.

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Feeling or showing sympathy and concern for others:
>
> ORIGIN
>
> from Latin *compati* *"to sympathize"* form *com "with"* + *pati
>   "suffer"* from Greek *pema "suffering"*

"He was *compassionate* when I explained my hard drive fried over the weekend."

Answer (score 1):

***[Vulnerable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vulnerable)*** 1 comes to mind when you say "they can ask stupid questions fearlessly."

***[Brené Brown](https://www.ted.com/speakers/brene_brown)***'s 2 extensive research has captured a contemporary sense of *vulnerability*:

> "*Vulnerability* is not weakness, and that myth is profoundly dangerous.
>   *Vulnerability* is the birthplace of invitation, innovation and
>   change...*Vulnerability* is our most accurate measurement of courage."

The definition of [*vulnerable*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vulnerable) supports her claims:

> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1 Exposed to the **possibility** of being attacked or harmed, either
>   physically or emotionally:

"Johnny is *vulnerable* to the taunts of the bully, but he is learning to manage his fears."

In the workplace, our superiors encourage us deeply when they take practical and emotional risks to connect with us at a human level that complements our professional relationship. We refer to those practical and emotional risks as *vulnerability*.

People who are easy to talk to extend small opportunities for us to "harm" them emotionally, because they have a [deep inner courage and strength](https://www.ted.com/talks/brene_brown_on_vulnerability/transcript?language=en) 3 to connect with us no matter what we say.

1. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vulnerable
2. https://www.ted.com/speakers/brene_brown
3. https://www.ted.com/talks/brene_brown_on_vulnerability/transcript?language=en

Answer (score 1):

A person who is easy to talk to and is approachable is- 'affable'. Affable is an adjective. Source- English Oxford Dictionary and internet search. The word is derived from the latin word-"affābilis".

Answer (score 1):

"Sounding board" is a commonly used phrase.  For example, "Bob used Jack as a sounding board" means that Bob was comfortable describing problems to Jack.  It also means that Bob could safely describe his opinions to Jack, before presenting his opinions to potentially hostile audiences.  In other words, Bob finds Jack to be easy-to-talk to, and helps Bob figure out what Bob means to say.

It can be assumed that if "Bob used Jack as a sounding board", then Bob and Jack know each other pretty well already.  The phrase says nothing (one way or the other) about whether strangers find Jack to be "easily approachable".

Answer (score 0):

Again not an adjective, but you might also say that such a person "invites confidences."

Comment: Your post would be improved if it included a reference and an explanation of why it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

*Sociable* is an alternative, and one that I'd use. Although it doesn't specifically imply that they're easy to talk to, it does connote that they're comfortable in all social situations.

> "Have you talked to the new guy yet? He's very sociable."

You could also use *social* in this way.

> "willing to talk and engage in activities with other people; friendly." - Google's definition

Answer (score -1):

I would say he's amiable. This suggests he is approachable and easy to talk to.