# A word for a person who has a "listening ear"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, obscure-terms

I am looking for a word that describes a person who is always willing to listen. He/She is your go-to person whenever you want to express your deepest thoughts, problems, and/or burdens.

The person is not necessarily a *confidante* since the shared information is not necessarily secrets.

> Alice is my closest friend, she's the one I turn to when I need a ________ (person).

Comment: "Watson", perhaps?

Comment: Close but not quite. :)

Comment: Perhaps just a good listener, an active listener, or a shoulder to cry on.  I personally would just keep it simple and say "John is a good listener.  I always go to him when I'm having problems."

Comment: @KumaAra Thanks for your input, but I would prefer a single word that captures the entire thought.

Comment: Are you looking for an adjective or a noun? I provided a sample sentence to allow both possibilities but if you only prefer a noun, just delete `(person)`

Comment: A *sounding board* is a person who will always listen and give you an honest opinion.

Comment: There's actually nothing wrong with using *listening ear* in that sentence (without "person", obviously).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A word for: someone who is easy to talk to](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/216440/50044)

Comment: Not a single word, but the idiom “shoulder to cry on” (http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/a-shoulder-to-cry-on)

Comment: Czar, how sad will you be when it turns out there is no such word, and you will have to settle for a phrase?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, I can live without the word, but life could be better.

Answer (score 2):

Not one word but:
**a sympathetic ear**