# What do you call a person who you tell your ideas, thoughts, plans to?

Tags: phrases

What do you call a person who you tell your ideas, thoughts, plans to? Whether they are related to love, life in general or work. Someone you open up to. In most cases that is the ONLY person you trust with certain info.

Comment: Is it my confidant?

Comment: There are various words for a subordinate who fulfils a similar role, e.g. amanuensis or Watson, but you can also have an equal, as noted.

Comment: Also a candidate duplicate: [a word for a person who has a listening ear](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412901/a-word-for-a-person-who-has-a-listening-ear) (confidante).

Answer (score 2):

Merriam Webster offers an amusing account of the necessary word (or words):

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confidante)
>
> Is it confident or **confidant**? (Or is it **confidante**?)
> If you find yourself unsure whether you should choose confident or confidant don’t feel bad; confidant comes to English from the French word confident, and when the word first entered our language it was often spelled that way, rather than as confidant. The difference is quite simple: confidant is a noun (meaning "a person in whom you confide things"), and confident is an adjective (defined as “having confidence”). You may well be confident in your confidant, but you would not be confidant in your confident. Although this distinction has not always been observed by writers, confidante is generally used for a female confidant. The word confidant is more frequently used to describe a man, but it may be applied to either gender.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the informal phrase ***bosom friend*** (British English) (with versions like *bosom buddy/pal* in American English):

> a friend that you like a lot and have a very close relationship with:
>
> - A bosom friend is someone you can be very close with and confide everything in. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bosom-friend))

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/bosom-buddy/) classifies it as *slang* and says:

> A ***bosom buddy*** is a very close, intimate friend, one who’s always got your back and who you do and share everything with